# How to verify that the mock doesn't return a specific return type

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to call an `Api`. If the call fails, I'm retrying with in the configured time out. When I'm writing the unit test for the scenario where the api repeated calls fails and the time out happens. I'm unable to determine what to Assert here. I think it's obvious to verify that the `mockedBaseApiClient` has never returned the response success for any of it's call in the execution. But I can't figure out how to verify the return type on the mocked object.

```
public async Task UpdateDocumentPath(UpdateDocument doc)
{
   var path = $"v1/documents/{doc.accountId}/{doc.documentId}/paths";
   try
   {
     var response = await _baseApiClient.PutAsync(DocumentsApiKey, path, doc);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {           
                var updatedDocument = await response.Deserialize<UpdateDocument>();
                var updatedPath = updatedDocument.documentPath;
      }
      else
      {
           await TryToReConnect(doc);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _exceptionPublisher.PublishException(ex);
       await TryToReConnect(doc);
    }
}
```

My Unit Test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task DocumentPatchAdapter_PatchDocument_RetriesWhenUnSuccessfullStatusCode_ButTimeoutExhausts_Tests()
{
 MockConfiguration();
 _mockedConfigurationSection.SetupGet(c => c.Value).Returns("20000");
  HttpResponseMessage notFoundResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
  {
     StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
   };

    _mockedBaseApiClient
            .SetupSequence(c => c.PutAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Object>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(notFoundResponse)
            .ReturnsAsync(notFoundResponse)
            .ReturnsAsync(notFoundResponse);

     UpdateDocument documentPathToBeUpdated = new UpdateDocument
     {
       accountId = 34512274,
       documentPath = "\\\\sharoi.vliproj.com\\DevL\\DocumentMaker\\Print\\InsuranceScoreRenew_19196100600.pdf",
       documentId = 3656261
     };
     await _documentPatchAdapter.UpdateDocumentPath(documentPathToBeUpdated);  
    //_mockedBaseApiClient.Verify(c=>c.PutAsync(.....)).NeverReturns(SuccessCode); I want something like this here          
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to verify an object you've already set up to return specific values?

Comment: I don't have anything else to either assert or verify that when time out happens then the document path is not updated.

Comment: But your code already specifies the return value of the mocked API client, it's like saying `var x = 1; if(x != 1) { thrown new Exception("Not 1!"); }`